# Backreference of char array of pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

I'm new to the `C` language.
While studying `char` arrays, I have a question.

I know a pointer to an array is the address of first element of the array. Below code is perfect:

```
char* c1 = "test"
printf("%s\n",c1); =>[output] "test"
```

But I thought that `c1` is the address of the letter "t," such as "00x1928." So, `*c1` is a backreference to `c1`:

```
char* c1 = "test"
printf("%s\n",*c1) => error!
```

Why is this code an error?

Comment: What you mean is "dereference". If `c1` is a `char*`, then `*c1` is a `char` and `%s` is not the right format specifier for `char`.

Comment: `*c1` is a `char`, not a `char*`. You want `printf("%c\n",*c1)`.

Answer (score 5):

`*c1` dereferences the pointer `c1`, which is declared to point to `char`. Therefore, `*c1` is a single `char`, which needs to be printed using `%c` instead of `%s`. To print *multiple* characters, you need `%s`, for which you need a *pointer* such as `c1`, but not an individual `char` such as `*c1`.

String literals like `"test"` are constant; you can't overwrite them. To prevent accidental overwriting, always declare pointers to string literals as `const`:

```c
const char* c1 = "test"
printf("%s\n",c1);
```

If you enable compiler warnings (always a good idea, especially when learning), you should get a warning for your original code.

Answer (score 1):

> I know a pointer to an array is the address of first element of the
>   array. Below code is perfect:

Yes a pointer to an array contains the address of first element of the array. However you are determining its type incorrectly.

Let's consider the following declaration of an array

```
char s[] = "test";
```

then a pointer to the array is defined the following way

```
char ( *p )[5] = &s;
```

Now indeed there is declared a pointer to an array of the type char[5] because the array s has five elements (including the terminating zero of the string literal with which the array was initialized).

So dereferencing the pointer you will get lvalue of the array.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "test";
    char ( *p )[5] = &s;

    printf( "The size of the pointed array is %zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The size of the pointed array is 5
```

What you mean is that arrays with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "test";


    printf( "The size of the pointed first alement of the array is %zu\n"
            "and the pointed element is '%c'\n", sizeof( *s ), *s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The size of the pointed first alement of the array is 1
and the pointed element is 't'
```

That is in this expression `*s` the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. Dereferencing the pointer you get the first element of the array.

To create a pointer to the first element of an array you can write for example

```
char s[] = "test";
char *p = s;
```

Again the array s used as an initializer of the pointer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. That is the expression `s`  used as an initializer has the type `char *`.